# Any use for Holiday Spirit?

Tags: starbound

I am a bit of a boring starbound player (don't build much, prefer to explore) so for me, is there any value to holiday spirit? or am I doomed to have a filed inventory slot until the next wipe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you build the [Toymaker's Table](http://starbounder.org/Toymaker%27s_Table) you can use the Holiday Spirit to construct a variety of decorations and gifts. As far as I can tell there is no "use" for them besides decorating your (or a friend's) house/ship/landscape.

Edit: Actually some of the clothes do provide warmth, so not *totally* useless.

Comment: We are talking 1 warmth clothing though, literally worse than starter set.

Answer (score 4):

Creating the Unusual Gift Boxes and placing them spawn gift box entities which when broken, provide pixels and under-powered BUT festive weapons.